# Laptop power plan seems to have no effect on the laptop going into hibernation

Tags: windows-10, laptop, power-management

My laptop goes to hibernation relatively quickly. Definitely within less than the 240 minutes I set in the power plan currently selected.

I'm aware there's a possibility of some additional software taking over the power management, but I have no clue how to find it if it even exists.

I am using a Lenovo Thinkpad E15 gen 2 running windows 10.

Comment: Have you looked in Lenovo Vantage?

Comment: See https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-sleep-too-fast/ for suggestions.

Comment: Also use System Update and update ALL drivers.  Reset power plans to default, use the Balanced Plan and set it up. Test again

Comment: When I have a problem with something like this, I go to my tried and true [Caffeine](https://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/#download) app.  It will keep your system alive for whatever you specify.  Also.. ignore the command line options shown on the beginning of the page, it is a GUI app that will run in your system tray.  No need to learn these unless you are trying to automate something.

Comment: Have a look in *Power Options > Change plan settings > Change advanced power settings* and open the branch of *Sleep > Hibernate after*.